# How to add 1 hour and 5 minutes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a requirement to show the pop up of every 1 hour 5 seconds, have set the time for 1 hour, how to set a time for 1 hour 5 seconds using Javascript.

for 3 minutes set the time for 3 * 60 * 1000;

for 1 hour set the time for 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

how to be for 1 hour  5 minutes?

Comment: ( 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)+5?

Answer (score 1):

Use date object and it's methods. `getTime()` will get the current date in milliseconds and add appropriate milliseconds for 1 hour 5 minute (which is 65 minute), which will be `65 * 60 * 1000`. And after use `setTime()` to create the date according to the milliseconds.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 65 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

1 Hr s= (1 * 60 * 60* 1000)

5 Sec = (5*1000)

Then

1 Hrs 5 Sec = (1 * 60 * 60* 1000)+(5*1000)